# IP Tables Issue on VPS

Tags: linux, iptables

Running a VPS with Centos 6.

If I run ifconfig, the adapter with net is named venet0:0-00

```
 venet0:0-00  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:hidden  P-t-P:hidden  Bcast:hidden  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

So I run this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it tells me, iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Does anyone see the issue?

I need to allow UDP/TCP traffic for OpeNVPN on many ports, 1194 included.  In past usage, the above command works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this IPtables feature is not virtualized within OpenVZ. This means you can not use it.